# PHP classes, parse syntax errors when using 'var' to declare variables

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, object

I am a C# guy trying to translate some of my OOP understanding over to php.  I'm trying to make my first class object, and are hitting a few hitches.

Here is the beginning of the class:

```
<?php

require("Database/UserDB.php");

class User {

  private var $uid;
  private var $username;
  private var $password;
  private var $realname;
  private var $email;
  private var $address;
  private var $phone;
  private var $projectArray;

  public function _construct($username) {

    $userArray = UserDB::GetUserArray($username);
    $uid       = $userArray['uid'];
    $username  = $userArray['username'];
    $realname  = $userArray['realname'];
    $email     = $userArray['email'];
    $phone     = $userArray['phone'];
    $i = 1;
    $projectArray = UserDB::GetUserProjects($this->GetID());
    while($projectArray[$i] != null) {
      $projectArray[$i] = new Project($projectArray[$i]);
    }
```

UserDB.php is where I have all my static functions interacting with the Database for this User Class.  I am getting errors using when I use var, and I'm getting confused.  I know I don't HAVE to use var, or declare the variables at all, but I feel it is a better practice to do so.

the error is "unexpected T_VAR, expecting T_VARIABLE"

When I simply remove var from the declarations it works.  Why is this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are mixing things up. **Before** PHP 5 it was

```
var $uid;
```

**Since** PHP 5 it is

```
private $uid; // or
protected $uid; // or
public $uid;
```

You can read about it in the [Properties documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> **Note:** In order to maintain backward compatibility with PHP 4, PHP 5 will still accept the use of the keyword `var` in property declarations instead of (or in addition to) `public`, `protected`, or `private`. However, `var` is no longer required. In versions of PHP from 5.0 to 5.1.3, the use of `var` was considered deprecated and would issue an E_STRICT warning, but since PHP 5.1.3 it is no longer deprecated and does not issue the warning.
>   If you declare a property using `var` instead of one of `public`, `protected`, or `private`, then PHP 5 will treat the property as if it had been declared as public.